# multi-platform eclipse project using git branches?

Tags: eclipse, git, branch, project

I have a fairly simple "C" project using eclipse.  I am using this as an intro to git and have the eGit eclipse plugin.  This project if fairly simple in scope.  THere are some platform independant source files and then platform dependant ones.  I have them organized as:

```
    src/
        core/      # platform independent code
            file1.c, ... fileN.c
        interface/ # platform dependant code
            fileA.c ... fileZ.c
```

The code should eventually run on linux (at least RedHat), osx and windows. These will all be "command line" executables but the interface code is truly different between the platforms. For example, if I were writing a PAM (Pluggable Auth Modules) module, Red Hat uses linuxPAM, OSX uses OpenPAM and windows does not do PAM at all (far as I know, there is no reason for it). The PAM include files and libs are different, windows will do something non-PAM.

I am hoping that eclipse and git can help with this.  My idea is to use git "branches" for each os type.  I have tried this but ran into a strange situation and that is why I am posting this.

I started this with the RedHat version as the git "Master" branch.  I created three branches from Master: linux, osx and windows.  I started working on the windows branch then went on vacation. When I came back I got the linux branch but it had been "polluted" by the windows changes. I *thought* I had checked all the windows changes in before vacation.

Questions:

1. are branches the right way to do multi-platform projects?
2. should the eclipse ".project" file and other metadata files be under source control?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Branches are not the way to do multi-platform projects. Branches are a way to manage code with different release cycles. In the multi-platform case all of your code will be released at the same time. To manage this, make a directory structure that makes the platforms clear (have a directory for each platform).

.project files certainly need to be checked into source control.

Answer (score 0):

Git handles symlinks relatively well, if you have code you want to only update in one branch for one platform, you could define a main platform, put a folder in there with the code you want to share, then in the other projects use symlinks to that folder. Note that you cannot branch for specific platforms after that (well, you can replace the symlink with a copy of the actual folder of course, might need arise).

Comment: Just stumbled upon this when looking for Git answers and knew the answer, sorry for the late reply.